# Как написать свой мьютекс?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

У меня есть тестовое задание для поступления на работу:

> Написать мьютекс на основе тасков и async/await. Принципиальное отличие от стандартного мютекса – не блокировка вызывающего потока.
>
> У него должны быть методы:
>
> - Lock() – возвращает таск, который выполнится только когда мютекс станет свободным, причем этот таск должен быть уникален для данного вызова. (Лок не должен пропустить более 1 потока)
> - Release() – освобождает мютекс.
>
> Использование:
>
> ```
> await mutex.Lock();
> //code
> mutex.Release();
> ```

Как это возможно сделать? Мне не нужно четкое руководство, но хотелось бы знать в какую сторону копать, какие-то статьи с написанием похожего, в общем все, что может пригодиться.

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Какие-то взаимоисключающие параграфы. Мьютекс обязан блокировать текущий поток. То, что не блокирует текущий поток, не называется мьютексом.

Comment: Быть может, под "неблокировать" понимается "не погружать поток в ядро", тогда ожидание можно реализовать на `lock-free`. О таком варианте я читал на `RSDN`. Там как раз обсуждали, что такой алгоритм без блокировок можно использовать в качестве мьютекса.

Comment: @mega, можете объяснить как это происходит?

Comment: IMHO идея понятна. Абсолютно не знаю, как это делать в C#, винде и M$, но она состоит в следующем:

запускаем поток, который в начале сам захватывает мьютекс. Если занят, то начнет исполняться, когда мьютекс освободится. Логически это то же самое, что в первых строках функции потока (в терминах pthreads) сделать lock. Т.е. в pthreads я бы просто проложил еще одну функцию.

А вот с Release() как-то сложнее. Не очень представляю (опять же глядя на pthreads) как реализовать (не влезая в код библиотеки/ядра) освобождение захваченного мьютекса другим (отличным от владельца) потоком.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мне кажется, такое может сработать (если я правильно понял, что имелось на самом деле в виду):

```
Task currentTask = Task.StartNew(() => {});

public Task Lock()
{
    Task ret = currentTask;
    currentTask = new Task(() => {});
    return ret;
}

public void Release()
{
    currentTask.Start();
}
```

(Не тестировал, доберусь до компилятора и отлажу.)

---

Update: Вариант сверху работать не будет при попытке одновременно взять несколько блокировок разными async-функциями. Вот прямолинейный вариант исправления:

```
LinkedList<Task> coldTasks = new LinkedList<Task>(new[] { Task.StartNew(() => {}) });

public Task Lock()
{
    Task ret = coldTasks.Last.Value;
    coldTasks.AddLast(new Task(() => {}));
    return ret;
}

public void Release()
{
    Task first = coldTasks.First.Value;
    coldTasks.RemoveFirst();
    first.Start();
}
```

Кто-нибудь придумает решение поэлегантнее, без явного списка?

---

Дополнение: в новых версиях .NET у семафора появилась возможность асинхронного ожидания, поэтому можно сделать более простой вариант: завести семафор объёма 1 и выполнять операции на нём. Это выглядит совершенно тривиально:

```
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(1);

public Task Lock() => semaphore.WaitAsync();
public void Release() => semaphore.Release();
```

Чтобы точно не забыть отпустить блокировку, имеет смысл упаковать `Release` в `IDisposable`:

```
public class AsyncLock
{
    readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(1);

    public async Task<Releaser> LockAsync()
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        return new Releaser(semaphore);
    }

    public struct Releaser : IDisposable
    {
        readonly SemaphoreSlim toRelease;
        internal Releaser(SemaphoreSlim toRelease) => this.toRelease = toRelease;
        public void Dispose() => toRelease.Release();
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
LockAsync l = new();

// где-то позже

using (await l.LockAsync())
{
    // тут мы под блокировкой
}
```

Comment: Можно показать как это используется? А-то мне как-то невдомек:)

Comment: @jojo97: вы же сами писали:

    await mutex.Lock();
    //code
    mutex.Release();

Comment: Да уже понял:)

Comment: Вроде код понятен, но картина его работы не складывается. Как минимум возник вопрос -  За счет какого механизма другие потоки не смогут успешно вызвать лок и завершить его, если он уже был вызван каким-то еще потоком?

Comment: @John: Ну, вызывающий поток будет висеть в await, пока возвращённый из Lock таск не завершится. А этот самый таск завершится тогда, когда будет выполнен Release предыдущей блокировки.

Comment: схема интересная. Заметил что в этих реализациях нет отслеживания потока который взял блокировку, так чтоб освободить мог только тот же. Мне казалось что это неотьемлимая часть мьютекса, хотя может что-то путаю

Comment: думаю в такой реализации нужно будет уже хранить пары (номер потока, таска), а не просто таски

Comment: @John: Для мьютекса — да, но это, как я понимаю, не совсем мьютекс. Вернуться в исходный поток может быть непросто, например, если код выполнялся на пуле потоков.

Comment: Поэтому наверно и нет асинхронного мютекса - задание с подвохом